# How to maximize the chances to get a good PhD position in algorithms

Tags: phd, job

I have a master in CS from a not too well ranked French university. I have excellent grade in algorithms and did a good master thesis (although I haven't tried publishing the results in it). my overall grades are good as well. What can I do to further maximize my chances of getting a good PhD position in algorithms? I am confident in my skills but do not have much to prove that.

I am guessing that trying to do some publishable research with my former master adviser is a good thing, but since his area of research is really not my cup of tea, is it reasonable to try to publish something alone?

How can I find problems to work on that are feasible and publishable?

Any other advices are welcome.

Comment: Why is your thesis material not publishable? Most Master's theses have a paper or two worth of material in them. Good quality publications to your name will speak volumes.

Comment: _I haven't tried publishing the results in it_ — Fix that.

Comment: Ok I see that publications are vital, thanks!

Comment: You don't *need* to publish on top-ranked conferences. Publishing something alone will prove crystal clear what you (alone) are capable of. That should help. Also recommendation letters the documents that @ArminMustafa mentions and enthusiasm, but nothing shows more enthusiasm than publications. Try to write them properly, in this context I think that is more important than showing algorithms that will cause a revolution in the area, you are not expected to do that, probably not even during your PhD, although that depends on your definition for "revolution".

Answer (score 3):

I have few suggestions for you:

When you are applying for PhD there are few documents which needs to be submitted along with your application like Your transcripts, Research statement/proposal, Resume, Recommendation letters etc.

Now what you can do is: Prepare a very good research proposal, since you believe in your skills make sure that you highlight them with some examples like previous projects, your contributions etc. Remember, your research proposal is read very properly, so if you are bale to justify yourself well that would work for you

Also in your recommendation, you can ask your supervisor to mention your skills, appreciate your strong point enough.

Also there is no harm in mentioning the reason of not having published papers in your cover letter.

I hope this answer gives you some insight to get into a good PhD position.